# Client never receives messages from signalr hub SendAsync call from controller .NET Core in production

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

This works locally without any issues however when deployed to azure app service my client never receives any message when calling REST endpoint in controller.

My `App Service` has `Web sockets` enabled on the server via the configuration settings in azure.

Referencing docs for how to use the hubcontext outside of the hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I have a successful opened a connection:

```
[2022-04-01T19:34:40.915Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://staging-env.com/hubs/notification?id=omz2rGgyuXw01QV6Vs6PbA.
```

I receive test broadcast we call from the client successfully:

```
Testing notification hub broadcasting 4/1/2022 7:34:40 PM
```

No error messages or information regarding a closed connection - everything pinging correctly in app logs.

I have a controller:

```
public class NotificationHubController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hub;
    private readonly ILogger<NotificationHubController> _logger;
    
    public NotificationHubController(
        ILogger<NotificationHubController> logger,
        IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub
    )
    {
            _logger = logger;
            _hub = hub;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendNotification(NotificationDto dto)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Broadcasting notification update started");
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("NotificationUpdate", dto);  <-------- no errors reported
        _logger.LogInformation("Broadcasting notification update resolved");
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace NMA.Api.Service.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub: Hub
    {
        public Task NotifyConnection()
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("TestBrodcasting", $"Testing notification hub 
                     broadcasting {DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
...
            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            });

...
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/hubs/notification");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Client:

(react js hook)

```
export const useNotificationHub = ({ onNotificationRecievedCallback }: NotificationHubProps) => {
    const [connection, setConnection] = useState<HubConnection | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const establishConnection = async () => {
            const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(`${process.env.REACT_APP_NMA_HUB_URL}/notification`)
                .withAutomaticReconnect()
                .build();

            await newConnection.start();

            newConnection.invoke("NotifyConnection").catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err.toString());
            });

            newConnection.on("TestBrodcasting", function (time) {   
                console.log(time);
            });

            newConnection.on('NotificationUpdate', (response: NotificationAPIResponse) => {
                console.log("Notification Recieved: ", response);
                onNotificationRecievedCallback(response);
            });

            newConnection.onclose(() => {
                console.log("Notification connection hub closed");
            })

            setConnection(newConnection);
        }

        establishConnection();

    }, [onNotificationRecievedCallback]);

    return {
    }
}
```

I make the request via Insomnia to post a notification via the endpoint. I get a successful HTTP status return. My logs tell me that the that the call was made and it was successful. Yet not data received in the client.

I'm not sure what to do from here. I need to be able to invoke client calls from REST endpoints but this doesn't seem to work and I've exhausted my ability to use google to find alternatives.

Comment: Is your client pointing to the local server instead of the one in app service? You're using process.env.REACT_APP_NMA_HUB_URL, was that updated with the new endpoint?

Comment: @Brennan - Yes - verified in the connection status in the console. `[2022-04-01T19:34:40.915Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://staging-env.com/hubs/notification?id=omz2rGgyuXw01QV6Vs6PbA.` - this points to the environment URL correctly.

Comment: Could please have a try what if, you change the endpoint path to  `endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notification");`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Updated the Map Hub routes to not have `/hub` - but this didn't seem to change anything. I also updated my Azure App Service to .net 6 (along with updating the API project to .net 6) and that didn't seem to change anything either. Locally I receive a test notification when calling my http rest endpoint. I never receive the socket data in production though.

Comment: While you are broadcusting the message did you had a chance to put debugger  on this? Does it hit the method? Is that broadcusting to client? Or where the action get lost? While broadcusting to while client receiving the message? Could you please confirm that?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - The HTTP Rest method does get hit. I confirmed with log statements. Log statements also confirm the call happens without exceptions with the output statement `"Broadcasting notification update resolved"`. But the client never receives the message.

Comment: Could you please let me know  how's your `client`, I cannot see your `client snippet` here.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - the client is setup in the reactjs hook (last piece of code)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing the issue because you are starting the connection and then setting up the `on` and `onclose` callbacks last. You should rather set up all of your callbacks first, and then starting the connection should be the last thing you do.

EG:

```
    // BUILD THE CONNECTION FIRST

    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`${process.env.REACT_APP_NMA_HUB_URL}/notification`)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

        // SET UP CALLBACKS SECOND

        newConnection.on("TestBrodcasting", function (time) {   
            console.log(time);
        });

        newConnection.on('NotificationUpdate', (response: NotificationAPIResponse) => {
            console.log("Notification Recieved: ", response);
            onNotificationRecievedCallback(response);
        });

        newConnection.onclose(() => {
            console.log("Notification connection hub closed");
        })

        // START CONNECTION LAST

        await newConnection.start();

        // NOW YOU CAN INVOKE YOUR METHOD

        newConnection.invoke("NotifyConnection").catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err.toString());
        });
```

Comment: While you are right that the callbacks should be configured before starting the connection, it's technically not required and would be a very small race condition that wouldn't be seen in this example. Especially since they've already said they can get a response for the 'TestBrodcasting' client handler.

Comment: I have switched around the code to match what you have. Unfortunately the same problem exists. I am able to invoke methods from within the client and get a response but calling into the hub via controller method still doesn't seem to work.